# Exercise in C with if and switch statements: Write code to convert 2 digit numbers into words

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

There's this exercise I'm trying to figure out. The assignment asks to convert a two-digit number in words, the output should be something like this :

```
Enter a two-digit number:45
You entered the number forty-five.
```

I'm still a total beginner to programming. I'm at this chapter in this C programming book, in the exercise section about the `switch` and `if` statements. The exercise suggests to use **two `switch` statements**, One for the tens and the other one for units, but numbers within `11` and `19` require special treatment.

The problem is that I'm trying to figure out what should I do for numbers between `11` and `19`, I was thinking to use the `if` statement but then the second `switch` function would include in the output and it would turn into something like **`You've entered the number eleven one.`**

This is the program I've been writing so far (incomplete):

```c
    int digits;

    printf("Enter a two-digit number:");

    scanf("%d", &digits);

    printf("You entered the number ");

    switch (digits / 10) {
    case 20:
        printf("twenty-");break;
    case 30:
        printf("thirty-");break;
    case 40:
        printf("forty-");break;
    case 50:
        printf("fifty-");break;
    case 60:
        printf("sixty-");break;
    case 70:
        printf("seventy-");break;
    case 80:
        printf("eighty-");break;
    case 90:
        printf("ninety-");break;
    }

    switch (digits % 10) {
    case 1:
        printf("one.");break;
    case 2:
        printf("two.");break;
    case 3:
        printf("three.");break;
    case 4:
        printf("four.");break;
    case 5:
        printf("five."); break;
    case 6:
        printf("six.");break;
    case 7:
        printf("seven.");break;
    case 8:
        printf("eight.");break;
    case 9:
        printf("nine.");break;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Not sure I'd worry about converting the 2 digits into an integer - easier and more efficient to `switch(string[0]) { case '0': ...`.. You'd want a generic "`do_uints()` function for the common cases (e.g. `case '2': printf("twenty"); do_units(string[1]); break;` so that it's easy to use something else for numbers from 00 to 19 (where you might have a nested switch, like `case '1': switch(string[1]) { case '0': printf("Ten"); break; case '1': printf("Eleven"); ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the switch use these if then else statements.

```
if (digits == 11) {
    printf("eleven");
}
else if (digits == 12) {
    printf("twelve");
}
else if  (... ) {// similar statements for 13 14 15 16 17 18 19


}
// now figure out where do the switch statements have to be inserted
else {
    
     // here?
}
// or here?
```

The above solution assumes you haven't learnt arrays yet. If you have learnt  or know to use arrays - there are ways to improve this code.

Comment: I haven't learnt arrays yet so I have very limited options.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a good problem for a learner, do not want to give much away

```
// Pseudo code
int print_two_digits(int tens, int ones) {
  if (tens 2 or more) 
    print tens_place(tens) // use `tens` to index an array of strings.
    if (ones == 0) return;
    print -
  else 
    ones += tens*10;

  print ones_text(ones) // ones is 0-19 at this point. Index an string array with `ones`
}
```

---

How to index a string array and print?

```
// index: valid for 0,1,2
void print rgb(int index) {
  const char *primary[] = { "red", "green", "blue" };
  puts(primary[index]);
}
```

---

Trivia: English numbers in text 10-99 are mostly big-endian, most significant first as in "**forty**-two", except for [11-19] which has the smaller digit first as in "**four**teen".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write a function with 3 switches instead of 2:

- a first `switch` to handle special cases such as `0` and the numbers from `10` to `19` and return directly.
- a second `switch` to handle tens from 20 and print the word without a trailing dash,
- an `if` statement where you test if you need a dash,
- a third `switch` where you handle units.